# not able to load html page jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a list view in the page and want to click on an li item and go to another page. I keep getting unchromium error (in logcat) and nothing happens. I have it defined this way:

```
<li style="height:80px;"> 
    <a href="./assets/www/specificCategory.html">الكمبيوترات
        <img src="img/pc.png" width="40" height="40" alt="computers">
    </a>
</li>
```

is it something to do with href? i have a page under www directory called specificCategory.html

Error:

11-17 19:55:43.322: D/CordovaLog(26948): null: Line 1 : exception firing resume event from native
11-17 19:55:43.322: I/Web Console(26948): exception firing resume event from native at null:1
11-17 19:55:44.313: D/CordovaActivity(26948): onMessage(spinner,stop)
11-17 19:55:47.766: D/chromium(26948): Unknown chromium error: -6

Comment: can you share the error message?

Comment: got it to work with removing all that is before specificCategory.html. Strangely this failed to work previously.